# is it possible to have gwt rpc in smartgwt?

Tags: gwt, rpc, smartgwt

I was creating an application with gwt. then I found that smartgwt widgets are easier to use. with the help of the smargwt showcase I managed to create some working stuff. Now I want to add some previously created gwt composite widgets. but when do so the gwt rpc calls are failing.

- Is it possible to use gwt rpc calls with smartgwt?
- if yes how?
- or is there any big differences between smartgwt and gwt due to which the gwt rpc's can't be used in smartgwt?

Comment: yes, possible to do rpc same way.can you show some error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is possible to use gwt rpc calls in smartgwt in the same way.

If you are getting any problems then provide description about your problem like exceptions or error you are getting.

Comment: I'm only getting a [WARN] 404 - POST /profilegui/greet (127.0.0.1) 1402 bytes warning in the console. and rpc failure in the callback. let me check it. I thought it is not possible to use rpc's  in smartgwt. thanks for the pointer :)